# Only make allday events selectable in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to make only events which are allday selectable in fullcalendar?

I added

```
    eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
        if (event.allDay==false)
            revertFunc();
    },
```

which causes the event to snap back in place if it is not an `allDay` event. But is it possible to not make non-allday events not selectable at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use eventRender to disable the event if it not an allDay event. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    if(event.allDay == false) {
            event.editable = false;
    }
},
```